# Block editor not loading with rest api custom code

Tags: block-editor, rest-api

We have a custom code to delete Divi's shortcodes in rest api. To achieve that, we have this code with rest_api_init in functions.php. For some reason, this code avoids the block editor to load when we want to write posts. Can some shed me some light about what is happening?

```php
    add_action( 'rest_api_init', function (){
        register_rest_field(
            'post',
            'content',
            array(
                'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema'          => null,
            )
        );
        register_rest_field(
            'post',
            'excerpt',
            array(
                'get_callback'    => 'ap3_divi_do_shortcodes',
                'update_callback' => null,
                'schema'          => null,
            )
        );
    });

---

     function ap3_divi_do_shortcodes( $object, $field_name, $request ) {
        ob_start();
        global $wp_query;
       $wp_query->is_singular = true;
        if( !defined('ONLY_ONCE_ap3_divi_do_shortcodes') && function_exists('et_builder_init_global_settings') && function_exists('et_builder_add_main_elements') ) {
            define('ONLY_ONCE_ap3_divi_do_shortcodes', true);
          et_builder_add_main_elements();
        }
        global $post;
        $post = get_post($object['id']);
        $output = array();
        //Apply the_content's filter, one of them interpret shortcodes
     switch( $field_name ) {
            case 'content':
                $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
                break;
            case 'excerpt':
                $output['rendered'] =  apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', $post->post_excerpt );
                break;
        }
        $output['protected'] = false;
        return $output;
        ob_end_flush();
    
    }
```

Comment: what was the reason for using `register_rest_field` to try and override the excerpt and content? I've never seen this before and I'm surprised you were able to do it without some sort of PHP fatal error. `register_rest_field` can be used to _add_ fields, but I've not seen it used to _replace_ fields, and I wouldn't recommend it. Also if you remove the divi shortcodes then the block editor won't see them and they could be permanently stripped out on save. Would it not make more sense to filter the content and excerpts directly?

Comment: Also that `ob_end_flush` never gets called because it's _after_ the `return` statement

Comment: Thank you for your answer @TomJNowell
We override the content in the REST API, not in the content. It is because we use Divi and its builder inserts in the REST API all the shortcodes that are not needed because we need the text as plain as it can be.

How do you suggest we should do it?

Comment: @Manuls did you find a solution? I have the exact same problem.